# Getting title of a webpage issue

Tags: php

I want to get the title of a webpage with `file_get_contents()`,

I tried:

```
$get=file_get_meta_tags("http://example.com");
echo $get["title"];
```

but it doesn't match.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: because `<title>` isn't a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` != `file_get_meta_tags()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title tag is not part of match in `get_meta_tags()` function and it is also not a meta tag.

Try this:

```
$get=file_get_contents("http://example.com");
preg_match("#<title>(.*?)</title>#i,$get,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Regex `#<title>(.*?)</title>#i` matches the title string.

Comment: Use a DOM parser, not a regexp.

Comment: @Barmar why should I use Dom parser when it is much easier with Regexp?

Comment: Because the HTML might not exactly match your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below Code snipet to get the webpage title.

```
<?php
    function curl_file_get_contents($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }
    $targetUrl = "http://google.com/";
    $html = curl_file_get_contents($targetUrl);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    $page_title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "Title: $page_title". '<br/><br/>';
?>
```